# Array in a json

Tags: python, json

I am creating a python project who are working with an api, the api return an json like this:

```
    "1": "2018-10-13T08:28:38.809469028Z",
  "result": [
      {
        "id":3027531,
        "created_at":"2018-10-13T08:20:38.809469028Z",
        "date":"2018-10-13T08:19:38Z",
        "text":"banana",
      }
  ],
```

I can get 1, but i can't get text in result, can someone help me?

I tried:

```
response.json()['result']['text']

response.json()['result'].text

response.json().result[0].text
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see what you get back from `response.json()`, `response.json()['result']`, etc. You'll see what values are available, and that should get you on the right track

Comment: You write "an json like this" but what follows is not (valid) JSON. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, provide a [mcve], starting with actually representative data that you're trying to process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {"1": "2018-10-13T08:28:38.809469028Z",
     "result": [
     {
       "id":3027531,
       "created_at":"2018-10-13T08:20:38.809469028Z",
       "date":"2018-10-13T08:19:38Z",
       "text":"banana",
     }
     ]}

d['result'][0]['id'] # 3027531
d['result'][0]['text'] # banana
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
response_json = response.json()
response_json["result"][0]["text"]
```

The value for `result` is a list of dictionaries. We take the first item in that list, and then we ask for the value of `text`.

Be aware that this assumes that `response_json["result"]` has at least one item. If it is empty, you will get an `IndexError`. You should probably check the length of `response_json["result"]` before using it. Here is an example of how this could be done:

```py
response_json = response.json()
if response_json["result"]:
    response_json["result"][0]["text"]
else:
    print("result is empty")
```

Comment: I tried, and got `IndexError: list index out of range`,but the text is not empty  but thanks for the answer,

Comment: Ah, please see my edit. I included information about why this might happen.

Comment: I check before do this part of my code, so the json is same as my question but i got index error

Comment: If you are getting an index error, the json is not the same as it is in your question. Print out the result of `response.json()` and put that in your question.